# Programmatically finding if Android is installed

Tags: java, android, sdk

How to find out if user has installed Android SDK in his/her system and if installed version of SDK programmatically from Java? Is it possible. I thought to look from ANDROID_HOME environment variable, but I am considering a case where environment variable is not set. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path and ANDROID_HOME environment variables will be your first check.
If they are NOT set then (most likely) the SDK is NOT installed, but it is possible that current user does not have access permissions to it.
You can carry on and scan the file system too, but again the result will be affected by user permissions